# Filtering and $http promises in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've got a problem with filtering data from JSON file, which is an array of 20 objects.

in my factory I have these two functions.

```
function getData() {
    return $http
        .get('mock.json')
        .success(_handleData)
        .error(_handleError);
}

function _handleData(data) {
    var filteredData = _filterData(data, "name", "XYZ");

    console.log('filteredData', filteredData);

    return filteredData;
}
```

and here console.log("filteredData") shows only filtered elements (i.e. 3 out of 20);

next - in a service I've got this one on ng-click:

```
var filterMe = function () {
    DataFactory
        .getData(_address)
        .success(_handleServiceData );
}
```

where

```
var _handleServiceData = function (data) {
    filtered = data;
};
```

the thing is - why the 'data' in _handleServiceData shows all of the elements instead of these previously filtered?

edit: [here's the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FnlO4PIjHPTiWVYAQBC2?p=preview) - results are logged in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `filteredData` you return from `_handleData` function is not passed to the `success` callback you attach in `filterMe` function. That's because you attach that callback on the very same promise, since `success` function doesn't create new promise like the `then` method does. So to solve this modify your code like this:

```
function getData() {
    return $http
       .get('mock.json')
       .then(_handleData, _handleError); //use "then" instead of "success"
}
```

Then in `filterMe` function:

```
var filterMe = function () {
    DataFactory
        .getData(_address)
        .then(_handleServiceData );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because promises are asynchronous, and you seem to return the value of `filtered` to your caller [before it could be assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).

You should be doing

```
function getData() {
    return $http
        .get('mock.json')
        .then(_handleData); // then (for chaining), not success!
}
var filterMe = function () {
    return DataFactory
//  ^^^^^^ return a promise, not assign globals in async callbacks
        .getData(_address)
        .catch(_handleError); // I assume you want to deal with errors only in the end
}
```